# How to move project directory in IntelliJ IDEA EduTools?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA EduTools and chose a project from JetBrains Academy.  The plugin decided to create the project directory at some arbitrary location.  I tried moving it by choosing Refactor -> Move at project root but a message box pops up saying "This move operation can break the course".  I tried deleting the project directory and re-open the project from JB Academy, but EduTools seems to remember the decision and created the project directory at the very same location.

So my question is, how do I move the project directory to somewhere else?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this.

You can move the project directory anywhere using your File Explorer and import it back to your IDE using **Open or Import** on the Welcome Screen.

You'll see the project with the previous location marked as unavailable on the left of the Welcome Screen. Please click `⨉` to remove this project.